# Top header being overriden by the App content in Titanium for iOS7

Tags: header, ios7, titanium

My App has been running great with iOS 6 and before but with the new update to iOS 7, the app contents are being pushed to the top header of iOS 7, where the date and data provider logo appears.

How can I push down the app content so that there is a padding on top in Titanium 7?

Notice the black test on top.

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check what system version is user running and if it's iOS7 set 20dip to top property in main window:

```
// Function to test if device is iOS 7 or later
function isiOS7Plus()
{
    // iOS-specific test
    if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'iPhone OS')
    {
        var version = Titanium.Platform.version.split(".");
        var major = parseInt(version[0],10);

        // Can only test this support on a 3.2+ device
        if (major >= 7)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var iOS7 = isIOS7Plus();
var theTop = iOS7 ? 20 : 0

var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({top:theTop});

// Set the background color to non-black to see the status bar
// Or set the Window statusBarStyle property to a non-default value
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('purple');
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // Remove the status bar
    // fullscreen: true
    // Moves the Window below the status bar
    top: theTop
});
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({top: 0, title: 'BLAH BLAH BLAH'});
win.add(button);
win.open();
```

[image]

For more details and other known issues in iOS7 check [this documentation page](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide-section-37533766_iOS7MigrationGuide-LightweightWindows).